# Can one use dialysis tubing several times?

Tags: enzymes, purification

I would like to know, if one can use dialysis tubes multiple times. Or is there a risk of plugging the pores? I use the tubes for dialysis of a solution that contains a precipitated enzyme (183 kDa) and ammonium sulfate (132 Da). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a long comment than an answer, since I don't know. It could be okay, but if you are unsure whether it will work, is it really worth the risk? Here are some thoughts:

- With high AS concentration, there is an initial large influx of water which can stretch the tubing. If this is repeated several times you may stretch the pores to where they no longer retain your protein. You can determine yield after each dialysis to see if loss increases with use.
- Clogging up the pores seems like it could plausibly happen. You could add some low molecular weight dye to monitor whether the membrane remains permeable with use.
- Dialysis tubing costs like 5 ¢/cm. Unless you're using 10 meters at a time, it's really very cheap.